# Is there a method to use gmpxx.h together with c++98?

Tags: c++, xcode, gmp, c++98

Because of my project I need to use c++98 and gmpxx.h:

But even for a simple project, it doesn't work:

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>
int main()
{

    int xrange=5,yrange=5,component=5;

    return 0;
}
```

The error message is:
[image]

I tried using the following compiling methods

libc++: support c++11 and thus work

libstdc++: only support c++98 and do not work

Is there a way to use c++98 to implement gmpxx? thank you :)

Detail of errors when using c98++ to implement:
[image]
The breaking line is:

```
cout<<r<<endl;
```

But it works in c++11:
The error report:
[image]

Comment: So why is your compiler going in the `#if __GMPXX_USE_CX11` block if it is not a C++11 compiler?

Comment: oh.... I am very new in linux and actually I am not sure how that is done... When installing c++, I just ./configure --enable-cxx... I am thinking how to deal with it.... Thank you:)

Comment: What version of what compiler are you using? What command line is used by your IDE? Note that you can add `-D__GMPXX_USE_CXX11=0` to force `gmpxx.h` to use only C++98 code.

Comment: Oh, right, you are using a Mac, that explains all the nonsense. I assume the compiler is always `clang`, it defaults to C++11 (or Xcode defaults to calling it with -std=c++11), and you can chose between a recent libc++ or a prehistoric libstdc++-4.2. So you need to find where in your IDE you can select to compile as C++98.

Comment: Thanks, Marc, the problem is actually that one of the package I need to use only support c++98 while gmpxx.h requires c++11.... I tried force -D__GMPXX_USE_CXX11=0 but other parts broke down.....

Comment: gmpxx does NOT require C++11. As I said, you need to change the Xcode setting to compile the code as C++98 and not C++11. Also, what did break when you tried -D__GMPXX_USE_CXX11=0 ?

Comment: https://gmplib.org/manual/Headers-and-Libraries.html You need to *link* with GMP: `-lgmpxx -lgmp`. Ah, you already are since it works with libc++. The issue is that GMP and your program must be built with the same standard library. If you built GMP with libc++, you can't use libstdc++ for your program, sorry. But libc++ should work both in C++11 and C++98 modes.

Comment: Oh... thank you sooo much, I will try to build GMP with libstdc++ again, thank you :)