# compile gmp and gmpxx using libstdc++ on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode

Due to the restriction of my project, I need to use gmp(https://gmplib.org) (and gmpxx) with standard library libstdc++. Is there a way I could accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: gmp does not use the C++ standard library, only on the C standard library. So nothing to do.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your comment. but from one of my previous problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229930/is-there-a-method-to-use-gmpxx-h-together-with-c98 , it is required that I need to build it from libstdc++ so as to make it work.... Is it true???:)

Comment: Ah, gmpxx seems to do so. Just compile it with the same compiler and compiler-options as you use for the rest of your project.

Comment: yea... that's the idea.... actually I am very new to Unix and very new to c++ compilers and I just tried without success how to achieve that.... Thank you again sooo much:)